# How to separate Managed Metadata column values by a comma and display on one line?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, term-store, json-formatting, column-formatting

By default, it seems when you select multiple `Terms` from a `Managed Metadata` column in a `Document Library`, `SharePoint Online` will display each `Term` on its own line, eg:

```
Some_Tag_01  
Some_Tag_02  
Some_Tag_03
```

However, a `Choice` column that allows multiple selections will display selected options as:

```
Some_Choice_01, Some_Choice_02, Some_Choice_03
```

It looks like `Managed Metadata` columns are now supported in column formatting:

[Supported column types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#supported-column-types)

Is there a way to display multiple selected Terms separated by commas, so that they can be displayed on one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below JSON on managed metadata column:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

Or this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=join(@currentField, ', ')"
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: you read my mind with the second option, looks much cleaner, thank you.

Comment: i don't suppose you would know how to do this with values in a column of type `Person or Group`?  the above solution returns this on a `Person or Group` column:   `[object Object], [object Object]`

Comment: Can you please ask a new question for this & add more details to your new question. I will have a look into it. will be easier to manage it separately.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/294768