# How to change the delimiter used when displaying multilevel terms in a Managed Metadata column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, managed-metadata, json-formatting, column-formatting

The `Managed Metadata` column settings > `Display format` section looks like this:

[image]

In the Document Library, multilevel terms are displayed like this (i.e. with a `:` delimiter):

```
level_01_term:level_02_term:level_03_term
```

How can I change that to:

```
level_01_term > level_02_term > level_03_term
```

Based off [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/294210), I tried to apply [column formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=join(@currentField, ' > ')"
}
```

But it didn't have an effect of the displayed value.

Comment: Hi @user1063287, did you try my suggestion given below? Is it working for you?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint JSON formatting now supports `replaceAll` operator which you can use to replace all occurrences of colons from a managed metadata column.

Try this:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent":"=replaceAll(@currentField, ':', '>')"
}
```

**Reference**: [SharePoint: Replace All Occurrences of Substring in a String using JSON Formatting](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/08/22/sharepoint-replace-all-occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string-using-json-formatting/)

Comment: How can we add two or more conditions, for instance, replaceAll(@currentField, ' ; ' and  
' ;; ' , ' > ')"

Comment: Can you please [Ask a new question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with additional details, what exactly you are trying to do, what is the column type, maybe screenshot of list view how the data looks?

Answer (score 0):

**Join()** operator is only used in a context with multi-value field of type Person, Lookup, or Choice. multi-select person or choice field, it will not work for Managed metadata display value.

Then I try to use replace operator, however only the first instance of the value will be replaced.

[image]

Currently there is no OOB way to meet your requirements.

More information:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

Comment: Strange there is no built in method to `replace all` instances of a value, or a way you can set a global flag, as described here:  https://dmitripavlutin.com/replace-all-string-occurrences-javascript/

Comment: Use a Field Customizer for more advanced scenarios that column formatting does not support.https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer