# How to separate 'Person or Group' column values by a comma and display on one line?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

When you select multiple Persons from a `Person or Group` column in a SharePoint List, each value will be displayed on its own line, eg:

```
Person_01  
Person_02
```

However, a `Choice` column that allows multiple selections will display selected options as:

```
Some_Choice_01, Some_Choice_02, Some_Choice_03
```

`Person or Group` columns are supported in column formatting:

[Supported column types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#supported-column-types)

Is there a way to display multiple Persons separated by commas, so that they can be displayed on one line?

[This answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/294210) provides a solution for multiple options being selected in a `Managed Metadata` column:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=join(@currentField, ', ')"
}
```

However, when applied to a `Person or Group` column it outputs this:

```
[object Object], [object Object]
```

**Additional question:**

If I remove any JSON formatting from the `Column`, and click on the `Column` title in the front end > `Column settings` > `Edit` and set `Show profile photos` to `Yes`, then the values are shown on separate lines, eg:

[image]

Is there a way to get them to display on one line when `Show profile photos` is set to `Yes`?

The solution in the accepted answer causes only the text value to show, ie it removes the picture and surrounding styling.

I can see that setting `Show profile photos` to `Yes` wraps the individual values in a `<div>`, so I suppose it is just a matter of adding a `,`  between those divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show the names in one line using:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=join(@currentField.title, ', ')"
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: If you don't mind, is there a way to show selected column options on a single line when `Column title` > `Column settings` > `Edit` and `Show profile photos` is set to 'Yes'?   I have added further details and screenshot to the original question.

Comment: It is not as simple as it looks to add just a `, ` between two divs & show them on single line. Good understanding of HTML/CSS will be required to achieve this.